# How to insert rows multiple times to a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that I need to check if it has missing values in its rows. The second column must follow a sequence and if a missing value is found I need to insert it.

```
[[123 1 0
  123 2 0
  123 4 0
  123 5 0
  123 8 0
  123 9 0
  ...]]
```

In this example I'd need to insert at row 2 the values `[123 3 0]` and at row 4 `[[123 6 0], [123 7 0]]`.

I am iterating the array row by row checking if there is a missing row, using `numpy.insert` to do it, but it returns a copy every time an insert is done, increasing the index at which the rows should be inserted every time this operation is done.

Is this a reasonable way to do it?

Comment: Can you infer how many values are missing by looking at the first and last values? Then you can create the full sized array once and fill it sequentially.

Comment: It would be a bit hard as the array it's quite big

Comment: As @w-m suggests, look at only the first and last values and use `range` to build that column in its correct size. If the data in other columns changes, you will have to decide how those columns should be filled in your 'interpolated' positions. Can you provide any more context?

Comment: A common idea when inserting multiple items in a list is to start with the largest index and work back.  That way you don't have adjust the indexing for growth.  But adjusting for growth isn't hard; it's a simple arithmetic step.

Comment: If using `np.insert` it is better to collect all the inserts, locations and values, first, and then do just one `insert` call.  Because it makes a new array each call, it is relatively expensive to call it repeatedly in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this way without using insert:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[123, 1, 0], 
              [123, 2, 0], 
              [123, 4, 0], 
              [123, 5, 0], 
              [123, 8, 0], 
              [123, 9, 0]])
y = np.zeros((x[-1, 1], x.shape[1]))
y[x[:,1] - 1] = x
indexes = np.where((y[:,0] == 0) & (y[:,1] == 0) & (y[:,2] == 0))[0]
y[indexes] = [[123, i + 1, 0] for i in indexes]
```

So now,

```
print(y)
[[123., 1., 0.]
 [123., 2., 0.]
 [123., 3., 0.]
 [123., 4., 0.]
 [123., 5., 0.]
 [123., 6., 0.]
 [123., 7., 0.]
 [123., 8., 0.]
 [123., 9., 0.]]
```

Hope this can help you :)